# Caliburn Micro: How to add text to the bottom of a list box and display it

Tags: caliburn.micro

I'm trying to figure out how to add text to the bottom of a list box and display it.  In WPF with code behind, I would grab the ScrollViewer and manipulate it, but I can't figure out how to do it with Caliburn...

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options.

1) In your ViewModel you can call `GetView` and cast it to your view type and get a reference to the ScrollViewer.  Something like:

```
var myView = this.GetView() as MyView;
var myScrollView = myView.MyScrollView;
```

That works fine but isn't ideal if you're trying to not couple the view to the view model.

Option 2) is to implement IResult, see docs [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IResult%20and%20Coroutines&referringTitle=Documentation).

```
public class ScrollViewResult : IResult
    {
        public event EventHandler<ResultCompletionEventArgs> Completed = delegate { };

        private ScrollViewResult ()
        {
        }

        public void Execute (ActionExecutionContext context)
        {
            var view = context.View as FrameworkElement;
            var scrollViewer = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(view);

            //do stuff to scrollViewer here

            Completed (this, new ResultCompletionEventArgs { });
        }

        private static TChildItem FindVisualChild<TChildItem> (DependencyObject obj)
            where TChildItem : DependencyObject
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount (obj); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild (obj, i);
                if (child != null && child is TChildItem)
                    return (TChildItem)child;

                var childOfChild = FindVisualChild<TChildItem> (child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
            return null;
        }

        //this isn't required of course but comes in handy for 
        //having a static method and passing parameters to the
        //ctor of the IResult
        public static IResult DoSomething ()
        {
            return new ScrollViewResult ();
        }
```

Then you can call it like:

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> SomeAction()
        {
            yield return ScrollViewResult.DoSomething();
        }
```

Comment: I'll have to look closer at the 2nd one  The first one feels like it requires the VM to have too much knowledge about the view.

Comment: Yeah, that's why IResult is a good choice, the creator of CM talks about that on the docs page.